# Scanning numbers from file into array

Tags: c

This code for imputing these numbers into two separate Arrays are in the files listed like:

```
18 18 25 31 37 82 82 87 89 230 85 87 558
```

and

```
3 3 3 3 3 3 5 4 4 4 10 3 3 10
```

Neither work and the outputs are gigantic, examples being 2686616
2686632
4
1991898240
0
10027008
-352000039
0
2686632
1991898249
1991898624

Anyone able to help fix this?
Sorry this is just inside main it has suitable includes and main{}

```
FILE *locFile;
LOCFile = fopen("c:\\locvalues.txt", "r");
FILE *methodFile;
methodFile = fopen("c:\\methodvalues.txt", "r");


int locArray[13];
int methodArray[13];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    fscanf(locFile, "%d", &locArray[i]);
    fscanf(methodFile, "%d", &methodArray[i]);

}

for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", locArray[i]);
    printf("%d\n", methodArray[i]);
}

fclose(locFile);
fclose(methodFile);
```

Comment: I suggest you remove the "C++" tag, as the code in the question is barely C++. Doing it in C++ would be *very* different as well.

Comment: Can't test now but it seems you will need to take the spaces into consideration when calling fscanf.

Comment: Also, please show some *actual* code, or at the very least a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits your problem, because the code you show (besides having some mismatch in upper-/lower-case letters) should work fine. And you do check that the files opened correctly in your actual program? Oh, and the unexpected numbers, do you get them from both files or only one?

Comment: @thinker The `"%d"` format in `scanf` (and family) skips leading whitespace.

Comment: Check the results of the `fopen`.

Comment: I have tested it and it works fine on a linux environment. So, what environment are you using ? Please note that in line 2 it should be `locFile` instead of `LOCFile`, but I think you would have fixed that error in compilation.

Comment: The program should work fine as-is. Maybe you inadvertently printed the addresses ... &locArray[i] and &methodArray[i] ... that seems to be the only explanation for those large numbers ...

Comment: This code doesn't compile... Perhaps you are running a stale binary? Either ask a question about the error message(s) you see during compilation, or fix your testcase so that it compiles without us having to modify anything or fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, if you replace `LOCFile` by `locFile` on the second line, and recompile, your example code should run fine.